# Как сообщить js о том, что появились новые элементы в DOM-е

Tags: ajax, javascript

На странице аяксом подгружаются новые элементы.

Поскольку js подгружается до того, как появятся новые элементы, то для новых элементов скрипты не выполняются.

Как сделать так, чтобы скрипты выполнялись для всех элементов? Может, обновить их как-то на странице?

Пробовал необходимый js-код выводить вместе с аяксом, но так как он выполняется на странице несколько раз, то и скрипт у меня прописывается так же.

А следовательно и выполняется несколько раз.

Нужно как-то по другому.

Comment: Попробуй вот [это][1].
А вообще, нужно проектировать заранее так, чтобы не было таких проблем. 
  [1]: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы используете jquery, то используйте `.on()` - современный аналог `.live()`.
Если не используете, придется отлавливать момент создания новых элементов и заново привязывать все функции.

Comment: Я давно не смотрел обновления JQ, on() отныне следит за обновлением DOM?

Comment: Да, действительно. .live работает. .on() - нет.

Comment: В новой - до 2 версии оба варианта работают.
ПОсле 1.9 убрана в пользу on. ПРиведите пример кода, возможно, вы просто неправильно его используете.

Comment: установлен 1.8

Comment: @Радик Камалов

on() работает так:

    $('selector or element').on('event','subselector',handler);

т.е. у вас что-то такое:

    $('document').on('click','тут селектор как в live',function(){});

(вместо document лучше использовать контейнер в котором обновляются данные)

**.live()** не используйте, он устарел много лет назад.

Comment: Угу. Хотя лайв мне казался по использованию удобнее. Другое дело, я осознаю, что скорее всего, он перебирал все дерево при каждом обновлении. Сейчас уже привык.

Comment: @knes, мне кажется, что он всплывал событие всегда.